# How to install SSL to Ant Media Server when no internet connection?

Tags: ssl, https, webrtc

The WebRTC solution requires SSL(HTTPS) to run on remote computers. Ant Media Server provides a free quick solution for installing SSL to the server with just one click as explained here(https://antmedia.io/enable-ssl-on-ant-media-server/).
On the other hand, it requires an internet connection for installing SSL. 
Unfortunately, in our setup, there is no internet connection and how to install SSL to the Ant Media Server where there is no internet connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution for this.

The [blog post](https://antmedia.io/enable-ssl-on-ant-media-server/) mentions enable_ssl.sh script lets you use any SSL certificate. You can provide full chain file and private key file and dns name as follows. This operation does not need internet connection.

> sudo ./enable_ssl.sh -f {FULL_CHAIN_FILE} -p {PRIVATE_KEY_FILE} -d {DOMAIN_NAME}

enable_ssl.sh file is located at /usr/local/antmedia

Regards,
A. Oguz